# addColor rainbox text effect fails with bitmapdata

Tags: phaser-framework

For some reason, text.addColor() does not work when text is drawn through bitmapdata,  I am trying to do color changing manually by drawing two text labels to same position, but the problem is that ALIGN LEFT is not working well; any ideas how to change part of text to another color and/or why Align goes to center always?

```
let bmd = game.make.bitmapData(game.world.width, game.world.height );

text3 = game.make.text(0, 0, "testing", { font: "bold 20px Courier",align:"left", fill:"#ff0000" });
text4 = game.make.text(0, 0, "tes",{ font: "bold 20px Courier",align:"left", fill:"#ffff00" });

and update()
bmd.draw(text3, game.camera.x+(game.width/2), game.camera.y + (game.height/2));
bmd.draw(text4, (game.camera.x+(game.width/2)), game.camera.y + (game.height/2));
```

**This code works ok;**

```
    game.debug.text('rainbow', game.camera.x+(game.width/2), game.camera.y + (game.height/2),'yellow');
    game.debug.text('rain', game.camera.x+(game.width/2), game.camera.y + (game.height/2),'blue');
```